# Please help me fix a problem of tabbing

Tags: line-breaking, tabbing

I typed a paragraph in `tabbing` environment. I use `\=` to place tab, and `\>` to move to tab position. It's alright with short line. But with long line, it out of line width.
I don't know how can fix error. Please help me, here my code and resutlt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}

where \hspace{5mm}\= is the index for a typical neuron in the hidden layer \\
\> i is the index for a typical neuron in the input layer \\
\> $v_{ji}$ is the typical weight connecting $j^{th}$ neuron in hidden layer to $i^{th}$ neuron in the input layer //
% \> n is the number of outputs 
% \> $b_j$ is the bias and f is the output\\
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `tabbing`? It is for simple alignments but the text looks like it should just be in a normal paragraph or list. What text do you need to align?

Answer (score 3):

`tabbing` cells can't be broken across lines; you need a different approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just to show the margins
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength{\wherelen}
\newcommand{\where}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\wherelen}{where\quad}%
  \begin{itemize}[
    leftmargin=\wherelen,
    labelwidth=\wherelen,
    labelsep=0pt,
    align=left,
    nosep]
  \item[where] #1
  \end{itemize}}

\begin{document}

\where{
  $j$ is the index for a typical neuron in the hidden layer \\
  $i$ is the index for a typical neuron in the input layer \\
  $v_{ji}$ is the typical weight connecting $j$-th neuron in hidden layer
  to $i$-th neuron in the input layer \\
  $n$ is the number of outputs \\
  $b_j$ is the bias and $f$ is the output
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't forget to enclose math variables in the proper way; don't use `$i^{th}$`, but `$i$-th`. The Victorian age superscript “th” is frowned upon in typographic circles. I should acknowledge that a well known word processor imposes it to its users, but …

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I have the same situation when i use tabular, text still line out.
I found on web and see the people use tabularx to set width for table. But It's not working with me.
Please help me one more.

Comment: @phuong Please, make a new question